# Can't get ng-bootstrap to work in Angular2

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap-3, ngx-bootstrap

I've done everything exactly as described in the [documentation](https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/development/docs/getting-started/bootstrap4.md) but whenever I  test it I get this:

[image]

My Specs:

```
@angular/cli: 1.0.0
node: 6.10.2
os: win32 x64
```

Comment: Have you tried clearing cache?

Comment: As expected... nothing happened...

Comment: Configure your project as shown [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap). May be you might be missing something